# Atomically check if a file exists and open it

Tags: c#, io, filesystems, race-condition

I am trying to open a `FileStream` only if the file exists, and do something else otherwise (not create it, so `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` is not applicable).

However, simply checking `File.Exists` before creating the `FileStream` will not prevent race conditions as the file could be deleted before the `FileStream` has a chance to be created, in which case a `FileNotFoundException` would be thrown.

Is there a way to achieve this "natively", without resorting to the following try catch wrapper:

```
/// <returns>false if the file does not exists, true otherwise.</returns>
public static bool TryOpenFileStreamIfExists(string filePath, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, out FileStream fs, FileOptions fileOptions = FileOptions.None) {
    try {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) {
            fs = null;
            return false;
        }
        fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, fileAccess, fileShare, short.MaxValue, fileOptions);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        fs = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the try/catch wrapper in this case?

Comment: This seems like a proper solution already. The File.Exist call will handle most situations, and the catch will handle the exceptional case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use P/Invoke to call the Windows API's [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to open the file. This returns a null handle if the file can't be opened (although you'll have to call `GetLastError()` to determine exactly *why* the file could not be opened).

Make sure you use a P/Invoke declaration for `CreateFile()` which returns a `SafeHandle`, such as:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile
(
    string lpFileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile
);
```

If you do that then you can pass the handle to [the overload of the `FileStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fz1x84%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor which accepts a `SafeHandle`.

That's about as "native" as you're going to get...

However, I recommend that you just catch the exception.